# Splittig a column of a dataframe into two columns with multiple conditions-R

Tags: r

Let say I have such a dataframe(df):

```
header
---------
23.43
1,23
34.54
56.2
5,5
```

Some numbers are with dot(.) and some are with comma(,).

I want to split this column into two columns according to dots and commas into a new dataframe(df2) like:

```
header1  header2
------- --------
23       43
1        23
34       54
56       2
5        5
```

How can I do this using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Thanks a lot for the answers and for your time.

What about if the separators are in more than one character. For example:

```
header
---------
23 ab 43
1 ca 23
34 ab 54
56 ca 2
5 ca 5
```

How can we split this dataframe into two columns according to seperators "ab" and "ca"?

Comment: `strsplit(df$header, '[.,]')`

Comment: `tidyr::separate(df, header, c("h1", "h2"), sep = "[.,]")`

Comment: Also, `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(header, "[,.]", type.convert = TRUE)]` which will make the correct type conversion too.

Comment: @docendodiscimus `tidyr::separate(df, header, c("h1", "h2"))` will also work, as it has a default `sep = "[^[:alnum:]]+"`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that's interesting, though I prefer to be more explicit. Also, this will allow splitting on other symbols than just `.,`, as you know, of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @alistaire's comment you can combine `strsplit` (split the strings), `do.call` and `rbind` (bind results rowise):

```
df <- data.frame(header=c("23.43", "1,23", "34.54", "56.2", "5,5"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


r <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$header, "[,.]")),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(r) <- c("header1", "header2")
r[] <- lapply(r, type.convert)
r
#   header1 header2
# 1      23      43
# 2       1      23
# 3      34      54
# 4      56       2
# 5       5       5
```

Comment: I think `lapply(r, type.convert)` is the safest way

Comment: @DavidArenburg: edited. Why `type.convert` is safer than `as.numeric`?

Comment: Because you don't need to know the column classes apriroy. OP may some times have, character, logical, numeric, etc. This will always work.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Ok, thanks!

Comment: @DavidArenburg, `type.convert` will only work if you supply character vectors to it. So you probably need something like `lapply(r, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))`. See for example `lapply(iris, type.convert)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I know that. But the result of a `strsplit` is always a `character`.